# javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:

Tags: java, jsf-2, propertynotfoundexception, icefaces-2

I am working on a JSF2, Icefaces web application. I have the following view:

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{myFormBB.userRolesBean.userRoleList}" var="row">
    <h:column>
        <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{row.teamUser}" />
```

I get the below exception when I save the above `<ice:selectBooleanCheckbox>`.

```
Application caught instance of: javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException
["http-bio-8081"-exec-9] ERROR com.abc.mp.em.common.ui.exception.handler.ExceptionHandler - error
javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /sections/response/myForm.xhtml @599,78 value="#{row.teamUser}": Property 'teamUser' not writable on type boolean
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:849)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:731)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1109)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1109)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1109)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1109)
```

I have properly defined the property and its getter and setting in the backing bean.

```
protected boolean teamUser;

public boolean isTeamUser() {
    return teamUser;
}

public void setTeamUser(boolean teamUser) {
    this.teamUser = teamUser;
}
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it? Do I need to use a converter?

Comment: The setter seems to be OK. Are you sure, that the "row" contains this backing bean?

Comment: What is the JSF code calling it? It might be that you give to "#{row.teamUser} a non-boolean value.

Comment: If it is in an ice:selectBooleanCheckbox then you don't need a converter.

Comment: Row is list in BB, see below. '<h:dataTable columnClasses="columnA,columnB,columnC,columnD" rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row" value="#{myFormBB.userRolesBean.userRoleList}" var="row" border="1" binding="#{myFormBB.rolesTable}">'                           '         <ice:panelGroup>
          <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="iceInpTxt"
           value="#{row.teamUser}" disabled="#{erDetailFormBB.helpDesk}" />
         </ice:panelGroup>'

Comment: `<h:dataTable columnClasses="columnA,columnB,columnC,columnD" rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row" value="#{myFormBB.userRolesBean.userRoleList}" var="row" border="1" binding="#{myFormBB.rolesTable}">`

Comment: `<ice:panelGroup>
<ice:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="iceInpTxt" value="#{row.teamUser}" disabled="#{erDetailFormBB.helpDesk}" />
</ice:panelGroup>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> value="#{row.teamUser}": Property 'teamUser' not writable on type boolean

This error is basically telling that `#{row}` is a `boolean` (or `Boolean`) which in turn indeed doesn't have a `teamUser` property.

This in turn suggests that `#{myFormBB.userRolesBean.userRoleList}` actually returned a `List<Boolean>` instead of `List<SomeBeanWithTeamUserProperty>`. Verify and fix your model.